# Use Cloud Deployment Manager to upload SSL certificates

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am continuously trying but no luck. Below is the message I receive everytime I try

```
The fingerprint of the deployment is j6t0HcwFHHQifZteb2l3aA==
Waiting for update [operation-1553685800030-58511aa341085-accaf31f-b8a2d802]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1553685800030-58511aa341085-accaf31f-b8a2d802]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/infrastructure/resources/lb-ssl-certificate
  message: '{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.sslCertificate","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"The
    SSL certificate could not be parsed.","reason":"sslCertificateCouldNotParseCert"}],"message":"The
    SSL certificate could not be parsed.","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx/global/sslCertificates","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

**Below is my jinja snippet (sslcert-template.jinja)**

```
- name: lb-ssl-certificate
  type: compute.v1.sslCertificate
  properties:
    certificate: example.com.crt
    privateKey: example.com.key
```

Take note that **example.com.crt** and **example.com.key** is located in the same location as **sslcert-template.jinja**.  I am using a docker google/cloud-sdk to execute this. I am logged-in w/ my e-mail which has a Project Owner role

I also tried gcloud with certificate and key and it works very well

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create sample --certificate=example.com.crt --private-key=example.com.key
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx/global/sslCertificates/sample].
NAME    CREATION_TIMESTAMP
sample  2019-03-29T20:59:14.371-07:00
```

After some attempts.. I tried doing it in a python template instead and made the actual cert and key as values w/ defined as multi-lines and it just worked

Comment: It seems that your crt format error = sslCertificateCouldNotParseCert

Comment: Try to use https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html to check your key and crt .

Comment: @howie, this is so weird. I tried those cert and key in the portal and it is just working fine. My crt works just fine in `https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html`

Comment: I am beginning to think if my value `certificate` value is correct. I tried to enter a non-existing file and it is still `sslCertificateCouldNotParseCert` error

Comment: @howie, I updated my question staging that `gcloud compute ssl-certificates` works well with my provided certificate and key

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer since this is the top hit in Google for `deployment manager ssl certificates` as of 2020-06, even if there are answers further down the results list (but not on stackoverflow).

Deployment manager expects the file to be inlined in the yaml file, not as a path to a local file.

I.e., it should look like this:

```
- name: ssl-cert
  type: compute.v1.sslCertificate
  properties:
    certificate: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIUUVkDsK2nWJtToHzFjukeJzPyKaYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
      BQAwRTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQVUxEzARBgNVBAgMClNvbWUtU3RhdGUxITAfBgNVBAoM
      ...
      eDbQMIjIXvZNP6e3D3COn862l+OA/MjWjFVZnaraCpKByc1SBBaD1axQ/MY0jks=
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    privateKey: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIJpDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQIgqbfXwjdaNICAggA
      MAwGCCqGSIb3DQIJBQAwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECCKSeDnJWXINBIIJUHZOCaP6RbbM
      ...
      bru0DNVNlF4pMWzX6QaInsAPJoA63kS+
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to automatically inline a text file into the jinja template.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I updated my question with the answer a year ago. The only difference with your answer is you made it jinja but I made mine in `python` instead. But still credits to you, but I would not recommend doing this as it exposes your SSL credentials